# How do I create a horizontal scrolling website?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to create a horizontally scrolling website, but it feels that I am at a dead end. The website I want to create shouldn't have a horizontal scrollbar and it needs to "jump" from page to page when using the navigation links.

Here is a basic version of the website I currently have - [Horizontal Scrolling Project](https://codepen.io/j_r__n/project/full/DGkvqd/)

What I am trying to achieve:

The navigation links should be the only way of navigating and scrolling should have no effect on navigation.

Each module should be on a single page and it's very important that when a module is higher than the height of the page, it is able to scroll to the bottom of the module. The navbar and footer should also always be visible.

And last but not least, it should be able to work with Bootstrap 4.

Please note that I am not expecting someone to do this entire project for me, but rather that if someone could help me or knows of any resources I could check out, I would really appreciate it!

Code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-left">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <span class="main-link">
            <a href="#" title="Download" target="_blank" class="hover">Download</a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-right">
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!--MODULE START-->
        <div class="module col-sm-12 offset-sm-0 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-10 offset-1 text-center">
          <p class="title">01</p>
        </div>
        <!--MODULE END-->

        <!--MODULE START-->
        <div class="module col-sm-12 offset-sm-0 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-10 offset-1 text-center">
          <p class="title">02</p>
        </div>
        <!--MODULE END-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Made by Jeroen</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make wrap container with `overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto` properties, make your content blocks `width:100%;position:absolute` and position them using width of previouse  the block; e.g DIV1 `left:0`; DIV2 `left:100%` ; DIVN `left:N*100%` and navigate using js. It's kind of a carousel

Comment: You are looking for something like `parallax`

Comment: For single-page application use show hide of different `div`